# Adding a grob to patchwork plot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, patchwork

I have a function that returns a patchwork plot and I can't make any changes to. I would like to add a `rectGrob()` on top of it. When I try to do this I remove two of the plots.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + geom_point()
p3 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width), col = 'blue') + geom_point()

p <- p1 + p2 + p3

grob_top <-   grobTree(rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill='#F0F0F0',col= 'black')), textGrob('P1,P2, P3'))

grid.arrange(grob_top, p, heights = c(0.1, 0.9))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `patchwork::wrap_elements()` works better than `gridExtra::grid.arrange()`

```
patchwork::wrap_elements(grob_top) / 
patchwork::wrap_elements(p) / 
patchwork::wrap_elements(p) + 
patchwork::plot_layout(ncol = 1, heights = c(0.1, 0.45, 0.45))
```

Comment: Hi, I have multiple png files when I convert them to ggplot object, I am loosing quality. Is there a way to use patchworks directly on the png without loosing quality ? I have used magickr montage function. It maintains good quality, but patchworks give me more custom ability to annotate. Please let me know if there is a way

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```r
grid.arrange(grob_top,
             p,
             nrow = 2,
             heights = c(0.1, 0.9))
```

[image]

Comment: As mentioned, I have a function that returns a patchwork. In my example, that would be object p and therefore I can't use your suggested solution.

Comment: You can still call `p` as patchwork object, see my edit.

Comment: Seems to work in that case. But for example grid.arrange(grob_top, p, p, heights = c(0.1, 0.45, 0.45), nrow = 3) does not work. Is it possible to save a patchwork as one image somehow?

Comment: of course you can save a patchwork object using `grDevices::png()` and recordPlot()

Comment: Thanks for providing these functions. I provided an answer that worked for my problem.